# Returning NodeJS console value into client side (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I''m totally new to AngularJS and NodeJs. I'm having a promise and it works well. There's console.log here ,this works well in server console.I need to print this console.log into client side (It's in Angular JS).

This is my server side code.

```
function checkNamesAvailable(
  name /* : string | void */,

) /* :Promise<Object[]> */ {
  const connection = createConnection()

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  const sql = 
  `SELECT names
  FROM  Names
  WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(names, '$.name') = ? `
  const values = [name]
  const query = connection.query(sql, values, (error, results, fields) => {
    connection.end()
      if (error) {
        return reject(error)
        console.log(error)
      }
      resolve(results)
    })
  })
  .then((results) => {
      if(results.length > 0){
         console.log("name is already exist")

       }else{
         saveNewName(names)
       }
     })
   }
```

I'm calling above function in index.js as follows

```
    addresses.post = function (
  request /* : Object */,
  response /* : Object */
) /* : Promise<Object> */ {

  return authentication.authenticate((request.headers || {}).authorization)

  .then((authorised) => {
    if (!authorised) {
      return Promise.reject(boom.forbidden('You do not have access to add new names'))
    }
    libAddr.checkNamesAvailable(request.body.data.attributes.names)
    .then(() => {
      return response.setStatusCode(200).setPayload({
    })
    })
  .catch(err => {
    return response.setStatusCode(400).setPayload({
      message: err

      })
})
```

Could someone help me regarding this?

Comment: Where is the server side code to handle the HTTP request?

Comment: @Niral Munjariya - please check, I updated

Comment: You're resolving results in the "checkNamesAvailable" promise but not using it in addresses.post handler. You're setting blank payload.
response.setStatusCode(200).setPayload({})

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your error message to client.
As like:

```
res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' });
```

And inside your AngularJS controller, you need to catch this error. For example:

```
$http.get('/url')
    .then(function(result){
        console.log('good!');
    })
    .error(function(error){
        $scope.myErrorMessage = error.error;
    });
```

And now you can show it on the page

```
<div ng-if="myErrorMessage">{{ myErrorMessage }}</div>
```

Comment: I'm calling the above function in a index.js as  libAddr.checkNamesAvailable(request.body.data.attributes.name) and in my above function there's no response. I tried adding response and added your code as well. But it's not working. I updated method to full method

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code snippet:

```
  addresses.post = function (
      request /* : Object */ ,
      response /* : Object */
    ) /* : Promise<Object> */ {

      return authentication.authenticate((request.headers || {}).authorization)

        .then((authorised) => {
            if (!authorised) {
              return Promise.reject(boom.forbidden('You do not have access to add new names'))
            }
            libAddr.checkNamesAvailable(request.body.data.attributes.names)
              .then((results) => {
                return response.setStatusCode(200).setPayload({
                  data: results
                });
              })
              .catch(err => {
                return response.setStatusCode(400).setPayload({
                  message: err

                });
              })
```

Comment: Nothing happens. Do I need to change checkNamesAvailable console logs to return? I tried that too.

Comment: Is your checkNamesAvailable function resolves the results properly? Just try to log into the addresses.post handler.

Comment: Sorry , I yes when I console.log (results) I'm getting the output from API side. How do I show it in client side now?

Comment: Just try to access the response like response.data at the client side or just check what's the output on the client side.

Comment: I get it like this  $http.post(`${API_URL}/names`, obj)
      .then((response) => {
          console.log("DATA"+ JSON.stringify(response.data) ) 

Result is like this DATA""

Comment: Can you log the response only?

Comment: DATA{"data":"","status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null,null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:3000/v1/names","data":{"names":"Kavisha Ransara"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","authorization":"Bearer 
  })
} and finaly "statusText":"OK","xhrStatus":"complete"}

Comment: What it logs when you write console.log(response['data'])? It should print {"names":"Kavisha Ransara"}, If not try with JSON.parse(response).

Comment: Niral Munjariya- still I'm getting blank in client side. but in server side I'm getting the console output

Comment: Can you add jsFiddle?

Comment: response = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(response.data);

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Please check the type of response object using console.log(typeof response);

Comment: Hey ,thanx again..I have fixed that. Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021114/not-showing-the-return-reject-response-nodejs